# Fetching user ID for header

Tags: php

I'm having trouble calling the ID of a registered user in my database, to be displayed in address bar. I'm not sure what the issue could be. Here is the PHP code:

In signup.php:

```
if($reg_user->register($uname,$email,$upass,$code))
{   
$id = $reg_user->lasdID();  
$key = base64_encode($id);
$id = $key;
```

In verify.php:

```
if(empty($_GET['id']) && empty($_GET['code']))
{
$user->redirect('login.php');
}

if(isset($_GET['id']) && isset($_GET['code']))
{
$id = base64_decode($_GET['id']);
$code = $_GET['code'];

$statusY = "Y";
$statusN = "N";

$stmt = $user->runQuery("SELECT userID,userStatus FROM tbl_users WHERE userID=:uID AND tokenCode=:code LIMIT 1");
$stmt->execute(array(":uID"=>$id,":code"=>$code));
$row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
{
if($row['userStatus']==$statusN)
{
$stmt = $user->runQuery("UPDATE tbl_users SET userStatus=:status WHERE 
userID=:uID");
$stmt->bindparam(":status",$statusY);
$stmt->bindparam(":uID",$id);
$stmt->execute();
```

In my channel.class.php:

```
public function redirectchannel()
{
header('Location: index.php?id='.$userID);
}
```

In login.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'class.channel.php';
$user_login = new USER();

if($user_login->is_logged_in()!="")
{
$user_login->redirectchannel();
}

if(isset($_POST['btn-login']))
{
$email = trim($_POST['txtemail']);
$upass = trim($_POST['txtupass']);

if($user_login->login($email,$upass))
{
$user_login->redirectchannel();
}
}
?>
```

And in index.php (the user's landing page):

```
$stmt = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE userID=:uid");
$stmt->bindParam(':uid', $_GET['id']);
$stmt->execute(array(":uid"=>$_SESSION['userSession']));
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

On redirect the address bar simply shows "index.php?id=". The id is not being called.

Comment: And where is `$userID` set?

Comment: My bad. I edited the post to include verify.php

Comment: You're still not setting `$userID` anywhere.  So I would fully expect `header('Location: index.php?id='.$userID);` to redirect to `"index.php?id="`.

Comment: I'm fairly new to PHP. Can you tell me where and how I would set this variable?

Comment: Well, you would set it before you use it, and you would set it to whatever value you want it to have.  I'm not sure what you were expecting that line of code to do if you never defined that variable.  You might want to start with some introductory tutorials on PHP, creating and using variables is covered by any tutorial.